# Jenkins - Forbidden error 403 on private subnet EC2

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm learning devops and working on a project to install jenkins on an aws ec2 that is on a private subnet. Following the digital ocean doc, I was able to install it successfully and the jenkins service is running.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-20-04

I have an ALB setup to access Jenkins, but the target group is failing with the health check 403.

When I try to `curl` on `http://localhost:8080` on the same ec2 host or from the bastion host, I get an "Authentication required" error, and doing curl with -I gives me HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

I've spent a lot of time trying to get help on Google, but nothing worked and I'm kinda stuck here.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `/login` instead.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/login
```

Comment: thanks @ycr, that worked. I changed the target group to also look for /login path and now the status turned healthy as well. I still couldn't access it through ALB, though I have the correct sec groups. I'm going to continue troubleshooting.